# mongoose populate doesn't work on user shopping cart

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I have a backend in nextjs 14 and mongoose 8.0.3 for an e-commerce website .I have a user model like this :

```
import {Schema, models, model, Model} from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

interface UserSchema {
    username: string;
    password?: string;
    email: string;
    _id: string;
    wishlist: string[];
    cart: { productId: Schema.Types.ObjectId, quantity: number }[];
    role: "user" | "admin";
}

const userSchema = new Schema<UserSchema>(
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            lowercase: true,
            trim: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            select: false,
            required: true,
            minlength: [6, "error message"],
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            lowercase: true,
        },
        role: {
            type: String,
            enum: ["user", "admin"],
            default: "user"
        },
        wishlist: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Product",
        }],

        cart: [{
            productId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product", required: true},
            quantity: {type: Number, required: true}
        }],

    }
)


userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);
    next()
})

export default models.User as Model<UserSchema> || model<UserSchema>('User', userSchema);
```

and this is my product model :

```
import type ProductType from "@/types/product";

const productSchema = new Schema<ProductType>({

    title: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        unique : true,
        required: [true, "Please provide the title of the product!"]
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "Please provide the price of the product!"]
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "A product must have a description !"]
    },
    slug: String,
    images: [String],
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "Please provide the quantity of the product"]
    },
   
    categories: [String]

}, {timestamps: true})

productSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    this.slug = this.title.split(" ").join("-")
    next()
})

export default models.Product as Model<ProductType> || model<ProductType>("Product", productSchema);
```

in my app I need to populate both of cart and wishlist . to achieve this I do this :
 `const user = await User.findById(_id).populate("cart.productId").populate("wishlist");`

but the cart is not populated :
`cart : [{quantity: 1, _id: '6310832f78dc433010220977'}]`
I have two questions :

1.what is wrong with my code?

2.why there's an _id field in my cart instead of a productId field ?

Comment: `Schema.Types.ObjectId` is intended for schema types not TypeScript types. If you're using the actual type (in TypeScript context) use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`. Weird, I know.

Comment: You hash the password value on save, I feel like that's going to hash the hash, and hash the hash's hash, etc. If you want to store a password and hashed password. You should just hash the password before assigning it to the user model.

Comment: @BrandonBuck thank you for your answer. I'm sure it's not the reason bacause:
1.populating cart used to work properly before I changed the schema as above
2.user password gets hashed only when using save() method and I use it only once in my entire app and that's when the user signs up for the first time

Comment: You will have an `_id` property in each `cart` object because mongodb adds one for you as a way to uniquely identify each object (in this case mongoose actually adds it). From your returned results `cart : [{quantity: 1, _id: '6310832f78dc433010220977'}]` it is clear that you don't have a `productId` property in each `cart` object for mongoose to populate. Can you share a sample document to show what your actual document looks like in the database?

Comment: @MRT That was not an answer, this is a comment. I posted that as a comment deliberately because it didn't answer your question. It's a comment about other aspects of the code you've pasted that may or may not become problematic.